# Get specific element from an object list passed from controller in gsp

Tags: jquery, grails

I passed a list of objects from controller to the gsp with model as shown below

```
model: [ houses: houses]
```

I want to set in jquery that whenever the input value of houseId changed, the input value of houseName will be changed to the name of the specific house based on the houseId. Below is the code:

```
$( "#houseId" ).change(function() {
    $('#houseName').attr('value', '${houses[0].houseName}');
});`
```

As you can see, the '0' in `houses[0]` is suppose to be `houseId`, but I have no idea how to put houseId inside. Can anyone please enlighten me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this is sending the `houses` list as a JSON array and parsing it with JavaScript.

In your action:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
....
model: [ houses: houses as JSON]
```

So you have something like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"House 1"
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "name":"House 2"
   }
]
```

In your JS:

```
var houses = JSON.parse(${houses});
$( "#houseId" ).change(function() {
    var index = $('#houseId').val();
    $('#houseName').attr('value', houses[index].name);
});
```